# Issue in loading StoryBoard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I am facing issue with storyboard as in image. No component of viewcontroller is loading in storyboard. It is showing black screen instead. It is working fine in MacBook Pro but not in MacbookAir(M1 chip). I am using same Xcode vision(12.4) in both system.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Also I have added a view and set red colour to it but still no luck .

Comment: Can you show what you expect the storyboard to look like (i.e. what it looks like on your MacBook Pro)?

Comment: May be dark mode vs clear mode display ?

Comment: @Sweeper The view inside the view controller should be in red color as I set to redColor as view.backgroundColor(as in below image link).

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t9zK_gwenEUcj4uzVxQjzFUKD4K6O-hB/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you tried to change phone. Try to change from iPhone 11 -> anything and then back again. works for me sometimes.

Comment: @DanielLarsson I am just opening in Xcode and want to create some other page but all new viewController has same issue.

Comment: @Sweeper Actually I have created new project. Let me share the existing project's storyboard screenshot.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZXGCjAlApREv4w-hJ8tkY8T2xhJf46QS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That looks very much like an Xcode bug to me. You should report it to Apple.

Comment: It's not simple to guess the issue based on a picture. Go through following hints and you should find some clue. 1. Check AppDelegate and SceneDelegate if there is not override entry window, if they are consistent. 2. After running application use debug view mode in Xcode to see what screen has been initialised and what views are included + compare it on both machines. 3. Check if dark mode is not the problem. 4. Instead of using simulator use real iPhone with both machines (this way you exclude possibility of different settings for 2 simulators).

Comment: Guys, Issue has resolved by updating Xcode (12.5) and restart my system. 

Thank you so much for your support.